# Chrome Extension Message Passing - How to pass HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script, message-passing

I'm trying to send HTML from locally within a chrome extension to a div on the active tab. I'm sending the HTML via the background script and receiving with a content script injected into the active tab.

I've gotten the port to work and tested with various simple text-based messages. The div is also appearing, but it's blank, since the HTML isn't sending properly. Anyone know what is wrong with my code?

**background script:**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "sidebar");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.command == "read_sidebar")
        {
            //var sidebarURL = chrome.extension.getURL("sidebar.html");
            //console.log(sidebarURL);
            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.id = "test";
            $("test").load('sidebar.html');
            port.postMessage({command: "load_sidebar", html: element.innerHTML})
        } 
        else if (msg.command == "close_load") {
            console.log("told to close load");
        } 
    });
});
```

**content script:**

```
function loadSidebar() {

    var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "sidebar"});
    port.postMessage({command: "read_sidebar"});
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.command == "load_sidebar")
        {
            console.log(msg.html);
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").innerHTML= msg.html;
            port.postMessage({command: "close_load"});
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API can only send JSON-serializable objects, and HTMLElement is not serializable.

What you may try to do is to add your HTML to [`web_accessible_resources` section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) of the manifest:

```
  "web_accessible_resources" : [
    "sidebar.html",
    (any resources used by sidebar.html)
  ],
```

Then you can directly load the file from a content script, using

```
chrome.runtime.getURL('sidebar.html')
```

as its URL.

You can inject it as an iframe, or if it's static HTML, you can request it with XHR and manipulate the response.

Comment: Hmmmm I see. I'm trying not to inject it as an iframe, as the sidebar needs to interact with the DOM of the page. It's not static HTML (the html has angularJS). I'm not familiar with XHR. What is some documentation I can read in order to request with XHR and manipulate the response?

Comment: Well, if you don't isolate your sidebar from the page, all kinds of Fun Stuff will happen. So you might want to rethink that. XHR stands for [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). It can get you the raw HTML code, but it's not directly useful if it's not static.

Comment: Good point. I've made it an iframe and have successfully displayed the local html file. However, the angular code is breaking. I've included the angular and all other relevant scripts in the header, but I just see the plain HTML in the iframe. Can injected iframes use angularJS?

Comment: Did you include all of it in the `web_accessible_resources`? Don't forget to check the page's console to see what breaks (switching the context from <top frame>)

Comment: Yep, all included. The console keeps throwing errors on the Angular code, saying it isn't recognized.

Comment: Well, I personally can't help further; no experience with Angular, and it's a problem very specific to your code.

Comment: Is an array of URLs JSON serializable?

Comment: A simple test is to run `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` and see if it preserves what you need. By the [definition of the standard](http://json.org/), strings and numbers are okay, and so are objects and arrays of any depth.

Comment: @Xan "(any resources used by sidebar.html)" is not necessary. The resources within sidebar.html don't need to be web accessible in order to be used in the extension iframe.